# $form_state['rebuild'] and AJAX handlers

Tags: forms, ajax

I have form with the most common AJAX handler (managed_file field). In this field the user can upload a picture and after some processing a preview is available.

Also i have some inline JS which does some substantial work, which i want to be present when the form is submitted with wrong data. The solution for this problem was setting

```
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
```

Here a new problem occurred - the AJAX handler stopped working properly. Going to the log I found this message:

```
Invalid form POST data.
```

which was pointing to a URL with the error itself, here it is:

```
[{"command":"settings","settings":{"basePath":"\/","pathPrefix":"da\/","ajaxPageState":{"theme":"jv","theme_token":"ARZs9c7X77Aasa2fbJm0jb1KLUtqYD7h7UcVA6gygpM"}},"merge":true},{"command":"insert","method":"replaceWith","selector":null,"data":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022messages error\u0022\u003E\n\u003Ch2 class=\u0022element-invisible\u0022\u003EError message\u003C\/h2\u003E\nAn unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (92 MB) that this server supports.\u003C\/div\u003E\n","settings":null}]
```

What i get from this message is that the upload memory limit is exceeded.

This also happens to my custom AJAX callbacks - they also do nothing, but there is no error, just blank.

Can anyone help me what's going on and what's the best workaround if there is no solution to this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure out the cause to this?